# Passing a list of arguments to docker at build / run time

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile

I am writing a dockerfile where i want to download a **changing** set of git repos: repo1, repo2, repo3.
How should I supply these urls/strings to the dockerfile at image build or container run times?

I know one can pass an argument using the `ARG` instruction and using

`docker build --build-arg <var-name>=<value>`

But what happens when I have a list of args of arbitrary length?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you know you pass repo1 or repo2 or repo3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> dockerfile at image build

That's probably not the best idea, but you'd end up with env variables and use those in the dockerfile.

> container run times

This is, IMHO, a much better idea. If you know the command expects input, you can add this in the dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["git","-c","/tmp"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

We have a "hard coded" parameter for git, that is to say, everytime we run this docker container the parameter `-c /tmp` is passed to git. I use this as an example in case you need it, but it is not required and `ENTRYPOINT ["git"]` will work just fine.

In this case, CMD is the "default". In this case, we use "--help" as a way of helpfully telling the user they need to add a parameter.

You could make CMD be a default repo, or whatever you want.

IMHO, ENTRYPOINT and CMD should always be used in conjunction.

In case you are curious of why use ENTRYPOINT [] (this is the preferred form according to Docker), this is from the docker docs:

> Note: Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command
>   shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For
>   example, CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on
>   $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or
>   execute a shell directly, for example: CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME"
>   ]. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the
>   case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment
>   variable expansion, not docker.

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Answer (score 2):

## Build time

The best I can think of is to pass in a comma-separated list:

```
 docker build --build-arg repos=repo1,repo2
```

Docker won't parse this into a list for you, but the scripts run during the build could split the string into a list.

## Run time

If you define your command using `ENTRYPOINT` then any trailing parameters to `docker run` get appended to the entry point command.

So if your Dockerfile contains:

```
   ENTRYPOINT echo hello
```

Then:

```
   docker run myimage glorious world
```

... will run the command

```
   echo hello glorious world
```